# Tensorflow: while loop on tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I'm trying apply a while loop over a tensor's value. For example for variable "a" I am trying to increase the tensor's value incrementally till a certain condition is met. However, I keep getting this error:

> ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 3 for 'while_12/LoopCond'
>   (op: 'LoopCond') with input shapes: [3,1,1].

```
a = array([[[0.76393723]],
       [[0.93270312]],
       [[0.08361106]]])

a = np.random.random((3,1,1))
a1 = tf.constant(np.float64(a))
i = tf.constant(np.float64(6.14))

c = lambda i: tf.less(i, a1)
b = lambda x: tf.add(x, 0.1)
r = tf.while_loop(c, b, [a1])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument of the  [tf.while_loop()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop) should return scalar (the tensor of rank 0 is, actually, a scalar - that's what the error message is about). In your example you probably want to make the condition return `true` in case if all the numbers in the `a1` tensor are less than `6.14`. This can be achieved by [tf.reduce_all()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_all) (logical AND) and [tf.reduce_any()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_any) (logical OR).

That snippet has worked for me:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

a = np.random.random_integers(3, size=(3,2))
print(a)
# [[1 1]
#  [2 3]
#  [1 1]]

a1 = tf.constant(a)
i = 6

# condition returns True till any number in `x` is less than 6
condition = lambda x : tf.reduce_any(tf.less(x, i))
body      = lambda x : tf.add(x, 1)
loop = tf.while_loop(
    condition,
    body,
    [a1],
)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    result = sess.run(loop)
    print(result)
    # [[6 6]
    #  [7 8]
    #  [6 6]]
    # All numbers now are greater than 6
```

Comment: But if my input is for example: tf.constant([-3.238014281, 8 ,0.3])
How can I make my for loop apply the body ONLY on 8 and not the full tensor. Because with reduce_any, this is whats going on...

Comment: for example, you could set   condition = lambda x : tf.less(x[1], 12)  and
body = lambda x : tf.add(x, [0, 1, 0])

Comment: another approach is to send to the while_loop only the 8:   loop = tf.while_loop(condition, body, [a1[1]])

Comment: yea I understand but my tensor is huge, and I dont know the indices of what I will add...

Comment: If you have arbitrary array and want to increase only those elements whose value is greater than 6, than it could be done like this:    body = lambda x : tf.add(x, tf.cast(tf.greater(x, 6), tf.float32))

Comment: Oh sorry, I explained it wrong. again let's say this is the input: tf.constant([-3.238014281, 8 ,-3.3,...])  and I want to apply the less than condition to ONLY the values less than "i". With your last comment, I cannot add the value I want, right?

Comment: No problem, I got it, I have to multiply the cast with whatever value I want! Thank you very much, works like a charm!